# String replace not working?

Tags: javascript, string

I've been trying to replace to following string using the following...

```
var r = response.replace('var s = getService().getValue(\"join\")', 'null');
```

However, the String remains un changed and I can't understand why. The String itself takes the following format..

```
{"r":[],"c":true,"c":{"tags":
[],"":3023,"s":".src.util.S@6f4e9e57","class":"class 
src.util.dtos.DTO","Type":"public","c":"m","s":0,"de
fault":false,"id":544,"d":"","n":4,"na":"S","tagString":"","Pages":5},"results":[],"q":"","msg":"var 
s = getService().getValue(\"join\")
```

The actual string itself is a little longer but I hope you get the idea from that abstract.

Comment: Are you generating javascript code using javascript code? My GOD i hope not...

Comment: @Zoidberg, as he replaces with null I believe he has a javascript object, possibly some legacy system return value, and tries to remove any method calls to get a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your

```
var s = getService().getValue(\"join\")
```

part is a JavaScript code inside a JSON string, then you need to quote them again before replacing.

```
var r = response.replace('var s = getService().getValue(\\"join\\")', 'null');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the double quotes escaped in JSON are not supposed to be escaped inside a single-quoted string.

So, instead of:

```
var r = response.replace('var joinstakqueries = getService().getValue(\"join\")', 'null');
```

try:

```
var r = response.replace('var joinstakqueries = getService().getValue("join")', 'null');
```

Comment: I need the double quotes tho... they're in the string I'm trying to replace.. I have no access to that String so I can't change it.

Comment: @Skizit: That's fine. The double quotes can stay - just don't escape double quotes inside a single-quote string when doing the replacement. Otherwise it won't match.

Comment: I've tried your example and one with double quotes.. hasn't fixed it

Comment: @Skizit: Apparently the initial string was also single-quoted.